# What is the best method to code contact info in x/html?

Tags: css, xhtml, web-standards

What is the best method to code contact info in x/html **other than Microformats**?

Is the use of `<p>` and `<br/>` is ok? or do we have any other good element?

```
<p><strong>London</strong>
<br/>
607,5th Floor, Oxford Towers,
<br/>
Airport Road, Kodihalli
<br/>
London 560 008
<br/>
Phone: 91-80- 4115 1705-706
<br/>
Fax: 91-80- 41151707
<br/>
Email:<a href="mailto:abc@xyz.com"></a>
<br/>
Website:<a href="http://abc.com">abc.com</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Why not microformats?  Microformats can be heavily customized to whatever look you want it's about the style tagging....but have the benefit of me not having to copy/paste 5 times in your example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<p> and <br>` are fine, but as well as microformats, vcard contact details can be specified using microdata (http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html#vcard) or RDFa (http://rdfa.info/wiki/Tutorials)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `<dl>` tag to define a list of `<dt>` terms and their `<dd>` description if you want to better separate and maybe individually style every single item.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the address tag.
And youre allowed to use other tags inside, like br, p, a, etc.

```
<address>
    Name<br/>
    Street, City<br/>
    Country<br/>
    Phone
    <a href="">Your site</a>
    <a href="mailto:">Your mail</a>
</address>
```

Comment: Not unless it's the contact info of the page (or in HTML5, section) author.

Comment: Youre right.
But i would still put my post-adress in adress tags, even if its my contact page.

Answer (score 0):

Why not ?
It can be but as for me I prefer using divs.

or even tables.

Comment: div is standard container for data.

Answer (score 0):

Address element is used to supply contact information . 
http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/reference/address/